# Localizing an ownCloud theme

Tags: localization, owncloud

Is it possible to localize a file that is overridden by a custom theme in ownCloud?

According to [this issue in the bugtracker](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/1194) you can override theme files by just placing them in your own theme folder and editing them. In the case of the email templates, that are sent when you share a file with someone this looks like this:

```
print_unescaped($l->t("Hey there,\n\njust letting you know that %s shared %s with you.\nView it: %s\n\n", array($_['user_displayname'], $_['filename'], $_['link'])));
```

This relies on the localization feature, so when I change this text it will only be displayed in English, because the new text is not available in the language files.

I found localization files in `<owncloud>/core/l10n/de_DE.php`, which look like this:

```
$TRANSLATIONS = array(
"%s shared »%s« with you" => "%s hat »%s« mit Ihnen geteilt",
"Couldn't send mail to following users: %s " => "An folgende Benutzer konnte keine E-Mail gesendet werden: %s",
// ...
);
```

I assume that I could copy this file over to my theme directory too and add my translation for the new text, but that way I would lose future changes in the original localization file.

What I would like to have is the possibility to append (and ideally override) entries to the `$TRANSLATIONS` array in my theme directory.

The [official documentation about theming](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/developer_manual/core/theming.html#creating-and-activating-a-new-theme) is not up to date (it looks like it has been copied from the previous version without adapting it to changes) and does't cover localization at all. The [documentation about translation](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/developer_manual/core/translation.html) is not helpful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of ownCloud 7, you can edit the e-mail templates via the admin control panel.
About localisation of your text on [this](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/developer_manual/core/translation.html) link it is well explained how you can generate new language files.

In case the link goes down:
Make text translatable
In HTML or PHP wrap it like this `<?php p($l->t('This is some text'));?>` or this `<?php print_unescaped($l->t('This is some text'));?>` For the right date format use `<?php p($l->l('date', time()));?>`. Change the way dates are shown by editing /core/l10n/l10n-[lang].php To translate text in javascript use: `t('appname','text to translate');`